# Oracle - Adjacent Rollup of Hierarchial Data

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

Oracle 12c R1 - I am trying to build a dashboard for a sales organization.  Specifically, it is for sales forecasting (also called Sales Pipe).  There are two tables involved, a rep hierarchy table called IB_HIERARCHY_S and a sales forecast table called ALL_DEAL.

The IB_HIERARCHY_S table is very similar to the traditional EMP table that Oracle ships with… Instead of having an employee ID, the rep has a territory ID, and his territory ID rolls up to his Manager’s territory ID.  It is one row per person in the sales hierarchy, and the way to navigate up and down the hierarchy is by the TERRITORY_ID = PARENT_TERRITORY_ID. It includes the entire sales organization, from the lowest rep up through managers up to the organization Vice President. This hierarchy is approx 6 levels deeps.

```
IB_HIERARCHY_S structure

TERRITORY_ID  - primary key
EMAIL_ADDRESS –  email address of the rep
PAR_TERR_ID – parent territory ID, aka the territory ID of this person’s manager
…
```

The other table is ALL_DEAL.  This is a sales forecast table.  Each sales opportunity will have one row in this table.

```
ALL_DEAL structure

FIELD_REP_E_MAIL – email address of the rep.
TERRITORY_ID – Territory ID of the rep who is forecasting the deal
FISCAL_QUARTER – the quarter the deal is expected to close
TERRITORY_LOB – The line of business who is actively working the deal, Field rep of Telesales Rep
REV_TYPE – One of 6 buckets for the revenue
PIPE – a forecast dollar amount
```

The problem has to do with showing/comparing  MULTIPLE parts of the tree against each other.  Showing how a single rep is doing is easy…  Showing how a rep is doing against his peers is a little more challenging.  The real issue is comparing peers against each other that are NOT at a rep level, since you have to "rollup" and the PIPE of everyone underneath of them in the hierarchy.  Assume the VP has 3 direct reports, ‘Mgr-A’, ‘Mgr-B’, and ‘Mgr-C’.  Someone using this dashboard will enter the email address of ‘Mgr-A’, and wants to see how this manager compares against ‘Mgr-B’ and ‘Mgr-C’. We need to find the peers of Mgr-A, and then for all those peers, rollup the data of everyone underneath of them in the hierarchy.

I can find peers with this SQL

```
SELECT  TERRITORY_ID
        FROM IB_HIERARCHY_S
where par_terr_id in 
(select par_terr_id FROM IB_HIERARCHY_S 
     where email_address = 'Mgr-A');
```

This will return the territory ID of Mgr-A, Mgr-B, and Mgr-C.  My problem is how do I rollup the respective sales pipeline of everyone under Mgr-A, Mgr-B, and Mgr-C?

This is what I have so far, but it is not taking into consideration the fact that Mgr-A, Mgr-B, and Mgr-C are parts of an org tree, and the data beneath them needs to be "rolled up".

```
with peer_list as
 ( SELECT  TERRITORY_ID
        FROM IB_HIERARCHY_S
where par_terr_id in (select par_terr_id FROM IB_HIERARCHY_S where email_address = 'Mgr-A')
  )
select territory_id, fiscal_quarter, territory_lob, rev_type, sum(pipe) as PIPE,
grouping(field_rep_e_mail) as grp_email,
grouping(fiscal_quarter) as grp_1,
grouping(territory_lob) as grp_2,
grouping(rev_type) as grp_3
from smb.all_deal
where fiscal_quarter =  'FY18-Q2'
and TERRITORY_ID in (select territory_ID from peer_list)
group by rollup(territory_id, fiscal_quarter, territory_lob, rev_type)
order by territory_id, fiscal_quarter, territory_lob, rev_type;
```

Any help or ideas appreciated.

**ANSWER**

What ended up working is to identify (via a CONNECT BY query), all root and all leaf emails.  I then sum where ALL_DEAL in leaf emails, but group by root emails.

```
with peer_list as
 (SELECT  distinct email_address,             
        REGEXP_SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(territory_id, '/'), '[^/]+', 1, 1)  Root_Terr_Id,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(email_address, '/'), '[^/]+', 1, 1)  Root_Email
        FROM IB_HIERARCHY_S
        START WITH territory_id in 
(SELECT  TERRITORY_ID
        FROM IB_HIERARCHY_S
       where par_terr_id in 
      (select par_terr_id FROM IB_HIERARCHY_S 
      where email_address = 'Mrg-A'))
        CONNECT BY PRIOR territory_id = par_terr_id
order by email_address
  )
select <data> from ALL_DEAL, PEER_LIST
...
```

Comment: Please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of data in your tables and expected resutl for that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an inline view (subquery) showing all the peers and the subtrees under them. Then you join this view to the `ALL_DEAL` table and you do all the aggregation as you are already; you will also want to group by `PEER`.

To show how the inline view I mentioned earlier can be created, I will use the `EMP` table from the standard `SCOTT` schema. Suppose I want to create the view for employee 7566. (This can be hard-coded or it can be a bind variable; OR, you can create one table for everyone and do all the computations just once, create a materialized view from it, and any further comparisons and analysis will read the data from this big MV.)

So: Employee 7566. How can I get a table with this employee and his peers, and show all the employees under each peer? Here is how. Use the `connect_by_root` pseudo-column of hierarchical queries.

```
select connect_by_root(empno) as peer, empno
from emp
connect by mgr = prior empno
start with empno in ( select empno 
                      from   emp
                      where  mgr = (select mgr from emp where empno = 7566)
                    )
;

PEER  EMPNO
----  ----
7566  7566
7566  7788
7566  7876
7566  7902
7566  7369
7698  7698
7698  7499
7698  7521
7698  7654
7698  7844
7698  7900
7782  7782
7782  7934
```

Comment: This is close enough to get me where I need to be....  What ended up working was sum(leaf) by group by root in the hierarchy table.  I will add the SQL in my original question for others to view...